# Simple crowdsale

Tags: crowdsale, price

I want to do a simple crowdsale for lets say 500.000.000 tokens.

For 1 ether you will get 100.000 tokens. 20% will be holded by me, others goes to crowdsale. What wont be sold, it will be burned.

I did try multiple crowdsale contracts but i cannot make it work.

Biggest problem is with price. (example is from ethereum.org - with contract published on ethereum.org i get tokens back when send eth, but price is not good...)

```
        price = etherCostOfEachToken * 1 ether;
```

How can I make it that i will get 100.000 coins for 1 ether? Is there some contract example that will do that? I also tried Zeppelin and others but i cannot figure it out...

Thanks, 
Ales

Answer (score 1):

The formula should be really simple. Every internal amount is expressed in wei, it is better to use that unit to our calculation.

> 1 ether = 10^18 wei = 100000 tokens = 100000 * 10^decimals

Now if you send msg.value wei using the cross product you have to receive

> msg.value * 100000 * 10^decimals / 10^18 wei

It is recommended to always use 18 decimals for tokens in that case we can simplify, and if you contribute `msg.value` you should get

> msg.value * 100000

in tokens.

---

In the OpenZeppelin Crowdsale contract you should set the `_rate` to 100000 in the Crowdsale constructor.